# Laravel - Installing packages for older version

Tags: laravel, package

I am trying to install a package (https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth), and the site says that i requires Laravel 4.1. I am running Laravel 4.2, and so when I run `composer update` I get

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Why can't I install this on a higher version of Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install it on higher version of Laravel is because it's been just only support for `4. 1. *` of Laravel Version according to their [composer.json](https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth/blob/master/composer.json)

Comment: I understand that. I mean is there a way to force install it?

Comment: No, you can't force install because they just support 4.1 only! You should be taking an issue for it on their GitHub that to improve for 4.2